# Beaglebone Black SPI0 swap D0 and D1

Tags: beagleboneblack, spi, device-tree

On [elinux.org](http://elinux.org/BeagleBone_Black_Enable_SPIDEV) it is mentioned that it is possible to make D0 an output and D1 an input for SPI1 by changing the direction of the pins in the device tree and adding this line:

```
ti,pindir-d0-out-d1-in = <1>;
```

I tried to apply the same method, but with SPI0, and it doesn't seem to be working. I am working with a prototype PCB that may have other issues that are interfering.

Can someone confirm/deny that the same method works with SPI0 to swap its respective D0 and D1?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I have tested it on SPI0 and it is also working

For example I have changed in  am33xx.dtsi (dts overlay not supported after kernel 3.8)

```
 spi0: spi@48030000 {
        compatible = "ti,omap4-mcspi";
        #address-cells = <1>;
        #size-cells = <0>;
        reg = <0x48030000 0x400>;
        interrupts = <65>;
        ti,spi-num-cs = <2>;
        ti,hwmods = "spi0";
        //added to swap d0 and d1 in spi0
        ti,pindir-d0-out-d1-in = <1>;
        dmas = <&edma 16
            &edma 17
            &edma 18
            &edma 19>;
        dma-names = "tx0", "rx0", "tx1", "rx1";
        status = "disabled";
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this method with the spidev_test loopback program with identical results to the unaltered firmware. I think I have other issues with SPI that need to be addressed.

Here is the source for the "inverted" BB-SPIDEV0-00A0.dts:

```
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2013 CircuitCo
 *
 * Virtual cape for SPI0 on connector pins P9.22 P9.21 P9.18 P9.17
 *
 * This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
 * it under the terms of the GNU General Public License version 2 as
 * published by the Free Software Foundation.
 */
/dts-v1/;
/plugin/;

/ {
    compatible = "ti,beaglebone", "ti,beaglebone-black";

    /* identification */
    part-number = "BB-SPI0";
    version = "00A0";

    /* state the resources this cape uses */
    exclusive-use =
        /* the pin header uses */
        "P9.17",    /* spi0_cs0 */
        "P9.18",    /* spi0_d1 */
        "P9.21",    /* spi0_d0 */
        "P9.22",    /* spi0_sclk */
        /* the hardware ip uses */
        "spi0";

    fragment@0 {
        target = <&am33xx_pinmux>;
        __overlay__ {
            /* default state has all gpios released and mode set to uart1 */
            bb_spi0_pins: pinmux_bb_spi0_pins {
                pinctrl-single,pins = <
                    0x150 0x30  /* spi0_sclk.spi0_sclk, INPUT_PULLUP | MODE0 */
                    0x154 0x10  /* spi0_d0.spi0_d0, OUTPUT_PULLUP | MODE0 */
                    0x158 0x30  /* spi0_d1.spi0_d1, INPUT_PULLUP | MODE0 */
                    0x15c 0x10  /* spi0_cs0.spi0_cs0, OUTPUT_PULLUP | MODE0 */
                >;
            };
        };
    };

    fragment@1 {
        target = <&spi0>;   /* spi0 is numbered correctly */
        __overlay__ {
            #address-cells = <1>;
            #size-cells = <0>;

            status = "okay";
            pinctrl-names = "default";
            pinctrl-0 = <&bb_spi0_pins>;
            ti,pindir-d0-out-d1-in = <1>;


            channel@0 {
                #address-cells = <1>;
                #size-cells = <0>;

                compatible = "spidev";

                reg = <0>;
                spi-max-frequency = <16000000>;
                spi-cpha;
            };


            channel@1 {
                #address-cells = <1>;
                #size-cells = <0>;

                compatible = "spidev";

                reg = <1>;
                spi-max-frequency = <16000000>;
            };
        };
    };
};
```

Answer (score -2):

The documentation you are referring to only talks about the SPI1 D0 and D1 pin swap.

As far as I know, pin swap is not available on SPI0, only on SPI1.

Comment: If they were no swappable they would be called miso and mosi, not d0 and d1.